# Image Pre-processing for OCR (pytesseract)

Tags: python, ocr, python-tesseract, image-preprocessing

I'm trying to OCR image with pytesseract. Once I do the OCR for below image the result shows as "WV over"

What are the image pre-processing techniques that can be use to enhance this image by filling missing parts of text.

[image: text_image]

Enhance image OCR ability by,

- fill missing text parts in image
- Improve quality of image

Please let me know sample code that can be used to fulfil above requirements.

Answer (score -1):

can you try morphological operations like dilation and see if it improves ?

Comment: Thank you for your respond. I have try dilation but it is not working as expected. 
kernel = np.ones((5,5), np.uint8)
image = cv2.dilate(image, kernel, iterations = 1)